# quarto: figure panels showing up correctly in pdf output but not in docx

Tags: rstudio, figure, quarto

I have a manuscript in quarto in which I have included figures with multiple panels, like this:

```
::: {#fig-combined layout="[[50,50], [-25,50,-25]]"}
![Panel 1a](output/panel1a.png){#fig-1a}

![Panel 1b](output/panel1b.png){#fig-1b}

![Panel 1c](output/panel1c.png){#fig-1c}

A figure caption
:::
```

When I convert the quarto output to pdf, all figures are included and the layout is correct. When I convert to docx however, only the first 2 figures (1a and 1b) show up, and not figure 1c. Does anyone know why this happens and how I can fix this?